# Deploy with Bitbucket Pipelines NodeJS application to VPS

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm a bit new to Bitbucket Pipelines and I'm trying to set up a NodeJS api to automatically deploy to a digital ocean droplet and would really appreciate some advice as I have been trying to work it out for two days!

I've managed to work out how to scp deploy the dist directory that `npm run build` generates but am I right in thinking that I need more than that on the server?  i.e. node_modules, package.json etc..?

These are some examples of what I have tried..

sftp

```
image: node:10.16.0
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build API
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm run build
    - step:
        name: Deploy API PRODUCTION
        deployment: production
        script:
          - pipe: atlassian/sftp-deploy:0.4.1
            variables:
              USER: $USER
              SERVER: $PROD_SERVER
              REMOTE_PATH: '/var/www/live'
```

zipping it

```
image: node:10.16.0
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build API
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm run build
          - tar czfv appname-api.tgz dist/ src/ node_modules/ package-lock.json package.json tsconfig.json tslint.json
        artifacts:
          - appname-api.tgz
    - step:
        name: Deploy API PRODUCTION
        deployment: production
        script:
          - pipe: atlassian/scp-deploy:0.3.3
            variables:
              USER: $USER
              SERVER: $PROD_SERVER
              REMOTE_PATH: '/var/www/live'
              LOCAL_PATH: 'appname-api.tgz'
```

zipping it in various ways

```
tar --exclude='./git' -czfv appname-api.tgz ./
```

I suppose I could do a `deploy.sh` that does a git pull, but my repos are private and it would mean for each server I would have to add ssh keys etc so it's not ideal..